# How do I get the k-th minimum element of a Priority Queue in Scala?

Tags: scala, priority-queue

How do I get the k-th minimum element of a Priority Queue in Scala?

I tried the following but it seems to be wrong!

```scala
import collection.mutable

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val asc = Ordering.by((_: (Double, Vector[Double]))._1).reverse
    val pq = mutable.PriorityQueue.empty[(Double, Vector[Double])](asc)

    pq.enqueue(12.4 -> Vector(22.0, 3.4))
    pq.enqueue(1.2 -> Vector(2.3, 3.2))
    pq.enqueue(9.1 -> Vector(12.0, 3.2))
    pq.enqueue(32.4 -> Vector(22.0, 13.4))
    pq.enqueue(13.2 -> Vector(32.3, 23.2))
    pq.enqueue(93.1 -> Vector(12.0, 43.2))

    val k = 3

    val kthMinimum = pq.take(k).last
    println(kthMinimum)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add what did the code print and what do you expect to be printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the incompatibility between `PriorityQueue` properties and inherited collection methods like `take` etc. Another example of weird implementation issues with Scala collections.

Same problems exist with Java's `PriorityQueue`.

```scala
import java.util.PriorityQueue

val pQueue = new PriorityQueue[Integer]

pQueue.add(10)
pQueue.add(20)
pQueue.add(4)
pQueue.add(15)
pQueue.add(9)

val iter = pQueue.iterator()

iter.next() // 4
iter.next() // 9
iter.next() // 10
iter.next() // 20
iter.next() // 15
```

So, `PriorityQueue` maintains your data in an underlying `ArrayBuffer` (not exacltly but an special inherited class). This "Array" is kept heapified. And the inherited `take` API works on top of this heapified Array-like data structure. And first `k` elements of a min-heapified Array are certainly not same as `minimum k` elements.

Now, definition  a `PriorityQueue` is supposed to support `enqueue` and `dequeue`. It just maintains the highest priotiry (first) element and is just incapable of reliably providing k-th element in the queue.

Although I say that this is a problem with both Java and Scala implementations, its just not possible to come up with a sane implemention for this. I jsut wonder that why are these misleading methods still present in `PriorityQueue` implementations. Can't we just remove them ?

I strongly suggest staying with the strictest API suited for your requirement. In other words stick with Queue API and not using the inherited API methods (which might do weird things).

Although, there is no good way of doing it (as it is not something explicitly required for a `PriorityQueue`).

You can achieve this by simply `dequeueing k times` in a loop with time complexity of `k * log(n)`.

```scala
val kThMinimum = {
  val pqc = pq.clone()
  (1 until k).foreach(i => pqc.dequeue())
  pqc.dequeue()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's explicitly stated in [Scala API doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/mutable/PriorityQueue.html):

> Only the dequeue and dequeueAll methods will return elements in
> priority order (while removing elements from the heap). Standard
> collection methods including drop, iterator, and toString will remove
> or traverse the heap in whichever order seems most convenient.

If you want to stick to using `PriorityQueue`, it seems `dequeue`-ing `k` times or `pq.dequeueAll(k-1)` might be the only means to achieve priority retrieval.